# I can not close the Activity when opened a new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I open the first Activitiy. click on the button and move on to the second Activity. at the same time I want to first closed. and when you press the "back" does not appear from the backstack.

```
public void showUser(User user) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

and `finish();` does not work

Comment: did you try `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)`

Comment: try this.finish(); or getactivity().finish() if fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just writing finish() after startActivity() works

```
public void showUser(User user) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call startActivity(intent) from Activity A then onPause on A is called you can finish() A in onPause or try using A.this.finish() after startActivity(intent)